# Can we add Value in Redis List with Expiration Time in C#?

Tags: redis

I am using Redis queue and adding the data using **ListLeftPush** and reading data using **ListRightPop**. It works fine I am able to get the data. But what if data has not popped out? Can we delete old data? or Can we add **Value in Redis List with Expiration Time**?
   How to add time limit for each value while using ListLeftPush command in C#?

Comment: Welcome MaithiliS, what do you mean by "if data has been not poped out?"

Comment: Thanks for reply Ersoy.  
I mean if No one is listening on that channel for long time and still If we add(Push) data to that list.

Comment: How add expire tie for whole List in c#? **connection.GetSubscriber().Multiplexer.GetDatabase().ListLeftPush** is used for adding data into list. How to add expiration time in this case?

Comment: with `expire` command - i am not familiar with c# library but i think the command name is `KeyExpire`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to add expire time for individual value for the sake of keeping redis simple and fast.

you can only add expire time for individual keys i.e in ur case it is for whole list.

Answer (score 3):

No redis doesn't support that. Expiration is available only for the [top level keys](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/242#issuecomment-3512819). The closes data type/solution for your case would be `sorted sets`.

- You put your expiration time(timestamp) as `score` while adding to sorted set(`ZADD`)
- Instead of `LPOP` you use `ZPOPMAX` to get "**to be last expired**" element.
- Periodically you may use `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE` to remove expired elements.

For the demonstration i used smaller numbers as expiration dates.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 15 "a"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 25 "b"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myset 35 "c" 45 "d" 55 "e"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
 1) "a"
 2) "15"
 3) "b"
 4) "25"
 5) "c"
 6) "35"
 7) "d"
 8) "45"
 9) "e"
10) "55"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZPOPMAX myset
1) "e"
2) "55"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREMRANGEBYSCORE myset -1 15
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myset 0 -1
1) "b"
2) "c"
3) "d"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```